# Typeahead.js interferes with Bootstrap input groups

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

How do I keep Typeahead.js from splitting up my Twitter Bootstrap 3 input groups? Whenever I point the Typeahead javascript at a text area that's part of an input group, the joined text area and submit button stop being joined. Is this something that's just a bug in Typeahead, or is there a workaround for this?

Without loading Typeahead.JS:

[image]

With Typeahead.JS:

[image]

My original HTML:

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="tags" class="form-control" name="q">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
    </div>
```

This is what Typeahead does to this HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control tt-hint" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-size: auto; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat repeat;">
            <input type="text" id="tags" class="form-control tt-input" name="q" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;">
            <pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;">
            </pre>
            <span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;"><div class="tt-dataset-0"></div>
            </span>
            </span>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but there's a [project](https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less) which provides Bootstrap style for typeahead.js (both Less and CSS). You might want to try it.

Comment: I've got the same issue! Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: the project mentioned above partially helped to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This project partially solved the issue for me: https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less

The only outstanding problem is when I apply shadow effect to both the .btn and .form-control the shadow is drawn also between the input field and the button.

[image]

Comment: My workflow doesn't use less so this doesn't really work for me.

Comment: @schnauss Neither does mine, the solution is not dependent on less.

Comment: Works great, but one thing that is missing is: `.twitter-typeahead > .form-control{ width: inherit !important; }`. Add that to adjust the width of the input fields.

Comment: Simply incorporated typeahead.css (version 0.2.3) from the cited github page, added the link and typeahead (version 0.11.1) is working just fine.

Answer (score 31):

```
.twitter-typeahead{ float:left; width:100%}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect and should not be upvoted. This squishes them closer together, but it doesn't join them and it doesn't do anything about the left-hand side of the text box being square.

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap v4 solution:

```
.input-group > .twitter-typeahead {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   width: auto;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Though I didn't need the width: auto rule for my version, presumably due to using the css for other BS4 changes for it from here https://github.com/bassjobsen/typeahead.js-bootstrap4-css/

Comment: Almost perfect. Add this to remove the input radius at the left:
```.input-group>.twitter-typeahead > .form-control:not(:first-child) {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}```

Comment: This solution helped me solve the exact same problem for a blazored-typeahead component with bootstrap v5.

Answer (score 3):

maybe?

```
.twitter-typeahead > .form-control{
  width: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This fixes the problem when the left-hand side of the text box is square (not rounded):

```
.input-group .twitter-typeahead .form-control:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
}
```